# Fast image coordinate lookup in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a big numpy array full of coordinates (about 400):

```
[[102, 234],
 [304, 104],
  ....
]
```

And a numpy 2d array my_map of size 800x800.

What's the fastest way to look up the coordinates given in that array? I tried things like paletting as described in this post: http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/06/fast-array-manipulation-in-numpy.html but couldn't get it to work.

I was also thinking about turning each coordinate into a linear index of the map and then piping it straight into my_map like so:

```
my_map[linearized_coords]
```

but I couldn't get vectorize to properly translate the coordinates into a linear fashion. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `tuple` for indexing:

```
my_map[tuple(coords.T)]
```

This selects elements of the array via [*advanced indexing*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, had the coords in the wrong format. You have to transpose your array (amended)